# Duplicate SSH terminal window without logging in again

Tags: ssh, terminal

Whenever I work on the server, I find it very annoying to just have one terminal window. My problem is, that we use opiekey. So when I want to create another window, it takes time because I have to manually copy and paste everything in.

Is there a way to just duplicate my terminal window within the same SSH session so that I don't have to login twice everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is GNU screen. It allows you to open several virtual consoles in the same terminal window.

Comment: Agreed on screen, I also use [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu), which is an add-on script that gives me a status display as well as enumerating my open sessions in a status bar at the bottom of my SSH window.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/) , They'll allow you to run several consoles within one session.